# Parsing 'pseudo' XML (that is, not well formed) in java?

Tags: java, xml

I have some xml that looks like this:

```
<xml><name>oscar</name><race>puppet</race><class>grouch</class></xml>
```

The tags change and are variable, so there won't always be a 'name' tag.

I've tried 3 or 4 parses and they all seem to choke on it.  Any hints?

Comment: To parse anything there has to be a set of rules that the text meets - as it does not meet the rules for XML what rules does it obey? and how is it not well formed - your example is well formed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because it doesn't have a defined [schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema), doesn't mean it isn't "valid" XML - your sample XML *is* "well formed".

The [dom4j library](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/) will do it for you. Once parsed (your XML will parse OK) you can iterate through child elements, no matter what their tag name, and work with your data.

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
import org.dom4j.*;

String text = "<xml><name>oscar</name><race>puppet</race><class>grouch</class></xml>";
Document document = DocumentHelper.parseText(text);
Element root = document.getRootElement();

for ( Iterator i = root.elementIterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    Element element = (Element) i.next();
    String tagName = element.getQName();
    String contents = element.getText();
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This *is* valid xml; try adding an XML Schema that allows for optional elements. If you can write an xml schema, you can use [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) to parse it. XML allows for having optional elements; it isn't too "strict" about it.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML sample is well-formed XML, and if anything "chokes" on it then it would be useful for us to know exactly what the symptoms of the "choking" are.